# Mysql : How to identify table lock wait and unlock it

Tags: java, mysql

My web application code are written in java, swing, hibernate combination which runs in tomcat5. There are some situation when one table get locked while updating/deleting and not unlock by itself after some period of time [Error is: mysql lock wait timeout exceeded, try restarting transaction], which is resulting into inaccessiblity of application.

I have to write a java scheduler which will periodically check for lock status and after some specified time say 30 sec unlock the table.

To be specific ***I want to know how to check whether table is locked?*** and **how to unlock** it?.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same kind of problem, but my idea to solve it is different - I can't tell if it could match for you since you did not provide any details. As far as I know it should be impossible for you to unlock the table lock, since as it looks like it would not be the same thread that will try to unlock, and that will be rejected from DB.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [`GET_LOCK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) with a very low timeout to check if a lock is present. If the return code is 0 another thread has a lock, otherwise you get 1 and your thread has the lock.

As for how to unlock it, this is somewhat harder. It could be an entirely different application that is holding the lock, and it might be holding it for a good reason. I don't know if it's possible to force break the lock. But I don't think you would really want to do that.

Comment: I don't think it will work, GET_LOCK doesn't give the information about perticular table lock. Its merely creates a lock with given name.